# AddRaster using pyqgis

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, python-addin

I am able to attach a raster by using python console using the command shown below.

```
qgis.utils.iface.addRasterLayer('D:/Work/dt0017810q.tif')
```

But, when the same image/raster path is read from a text file using a customized plugin (which I developed), the addRasterLayer method/function throws an error message

> Invalid Layer: GDAL provider Cannot open GDAL dataset
>   D:/Work/dt0017810q.tif : `D:/Work/dt0017810q.tif ' does not exist in
>   the file system, and is not recognized as a supported dataset name.
>   Raster layer Provider is not valid (provider: gdal, URI:
>   D:/Work/dt0017810q.tif

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Just now only I find that while reading a line from a text file, \n will be there at the right end. I checked that value which was read from text file by using 'print' command. In print command, the \n is not displayed a character. Hence I confused.

Now the problem has been solved by using rstrip() function.